# Code not working in internet explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

The code below works perfectly in Google chrome but not Internet Explorer 8. I have not tested it in anything higher than Internet Explorer 8 as we have all XP machines here. is there a snippet i can put in to force it to work in internet explorer or am i using something that's not supported in Internet Explorer??

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


<!-- css for styling the button to make it appear as a link instead -->
button {background:none!important; border:none; padding:0!important;

    /*optional*/
    font-family:arial,sans-serif; /*input has OS specific font-family*/
     color:#069;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor:pointer;
}

body  { background-color:white;  }
block1{display:block; background-color:#E6E6B8 ; color:black; padding:10px; margin:5px;}
block1.a{display:none; background-color:#E6E6B8 ; color:black; padding:10px; margin:5px;}
<!-- End of the CSS Styling -->


</style>
</head>
<body background-color:#E6E6B8>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('ID').setAttribute('class', '');"> <b><abbr title="Click to expand">Current Status Report</b></button><br>


<block1 id="ID" class="a">
<p>
&emsp;<a href="#" >Current Status Report With Legal Process</a><br>
&emsp;<a href="#">Current Status Report<br></a>
&emsp;<a href="#">Current Status Report With Last Response<br></a>
&emsp;<a href="#">Current Status Report With Last Receipt<br></a>
&emsp;<a href="#">Current Status Report With Last Response and Plaintiff<br></a>
&emsp;<a href="#">Current Status Report by Date Transferred<br></a>
&emsp;<a href="#">New Business This Period<br></a>
&emsp;<a href="#">Letter Before Action Sent</p></a>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('ID').setAttribute('class', 'a');"><b>Hide -</b></button>
</block1>



<button onclick="document.getElementById('ID2').setAttribute('class', '');"> <b>Defended Cases (click for more)&nbsp;+</b></button>
<block1 id="ID2" class="a">
<p>
&emsp;Defended Cases<br>
&emsp;Cases Awaiting Affidavits<br>
&emsp;Cases where Judgment has been Obtained<br>
&emsp;Awaiting Instructions on Judgments<br>
&emsp;Cases With The Sheriff For Execution<br>
&emsp;Cases With Enforcement Proceedings Commenced<br>
&emsp;Instalment Orders Obtained<br>
&emsp;Instalment Orders Served<br>
&emsp;Cases Awaiting Instructions for Committal<br>
&emsp;Committal Summons Report<br>
&emsp;Forthcoming Committal Hearings Report<br>
&emsp;Outstanding Committal Warrants<p>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('ID2').setAttribute('class', 'a');"><b>Close - </b></button>
</block2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you described exactly what is "not working" :)

Comment: `<block1>` ?? `background-color` ?? `onclick` ?? Go back to html5 manual ;) IE8 should have Developer tools. Use F12 and switch to console then refresh page.

Comment: sorry yes basically on the click of the button it shows the information and then the hide button hides it again. lists should not be displayed by default

Comment: background-color and onclick are perfectly valid, but yes, that code :) Where the hell did you learn HTML ?

Comment: i know its bad but i stole from internet as it does what i want it to do - as it does in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have HTML comment in your CSS code**, that can break on IE8 :

```
<!-- css for styling the button to make it appear as a link instead -->
    button {background:none!important; border:none; padding:0!important;

        /*optional*/
        font-family:arial,sans-serif; /*input has OS specific font-family*/
         color:#069;
         text-decoration: none;
         cursor:pointer;
    }

    body  { background-color:white;  }
    block1{display:block; background-color:#E6E6B8 ; color:black; padding:10px; margin:5px;}
    block1.a{display:none; background-color:#E6E6B8 ; color:black; padding:10px; margin:5px;}
    <!-- End of the CSS Styling -->
```

Change it to :

```
    /* css for styling the button to make it appear as a link instead */
button {background:none!important; border:none; padding:0!important;

    /*optional*/
    font-family:arial,sans-serif; /*input has OS specific font-family*/
     color:#069;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor:pointer;
}

body  { background-color:white;  }
block1{display:block; background-color:#E6E6B8 ; color:black; padding:10px; margin:5px;}
block1.a{display:none; background-color:#E6E6B8 ; color:black; padding:10px; margin:5px;}
/* End of the CSS Styling */
```

**You also have major problem in your HTML : `<block1>` and `<block2>` are not valid HTML element**. Change them to `<section>`, `<div>`, or whatever is a real HTML element.

Some doc for you : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

*I'm very suprised that Chrome / Firefox render that correctly. This code is non-sense.*

Comment: your right after i cleaned up the code and got back to using divs it worked!! serves me right for copying code from the internet!!!

Answer (score -1):

Add following line in .

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

you can put ur IE version in content attribute.